# Excel find remaining columns efficiently

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script (thanks to SO for the help with that one!) to allow a user to select a number of discontinuous columns and insert their indexes into an array. What I need to be able to do now is efficiently select the remaining columns i.e. the ones that the user **didn't** select into another array to perform a separate action on these columns.

For example, the user selects columns A,C,F,G and these indexes are put into the array Usr_col(). The remaining columns (B,D,E) need to be stored in the array rem_col()

All I can think of right now is to test every used column's index against the array of user-selected columns and, if it is not contained in that array, insert it into a new array. Something like this:

```
For i = 1 to ws.cells(1, columns.count).end(xltoright).column 
    if isinarray(i, Usr_col()) = false Then
        rem_col(n) = i
        n = n+1
    end if
next
```

I am just looking for a more efficient solution to this.

Comment: If current code works, this may be more suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Make sure to add `ws.` before `columns.count`, otherwise it's going to count the columns on whatever the activesheet is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ScottHoltzman that this site wouldn't normally be the arena to make working code more efficient. However, this question puts a different slant on your previous one, as the most obvious solution would be to assign column numbers to one or other of your arrays in one loop.

The code below gives you a skeleton example. You'd need to check the user's selection for proper columns. Also, it isn't great form to redimension an array within the loop, but if the user selects adjacent columns then you'd need to acquire area count and column count to get the array size. I'll leave that to you if rediming within the loop jars with you:

```
Dim targetCols As Range, allCols As Range
Dim selColNum() As Long, unselColNum() As Long
Dim selIndex As Long, unselIndex As Long

Set targetCols = Application.InputBox("Select your columns", Type:=8)

For Each allCols In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns
    If Intersect(allCols, targetCols) Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve unselColNum(unselIndex)
        unselColNum(unselIndex) = allCols.Column
        unselIndex = unselIndex + 1
    Else
        ReDim Preserve selColNum(selIndex)
        selColNum(selIndex) = allCols.Column
        selIndex = selIndex + 1
    End If
Next
```